# Can reputations ever go negative?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Just curious if reputation points for a user can ever go negative?

Why?

Comment: Sometimes, I wish.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, reputation can't go negative, the reason being that people who get off to a poor start shouldn't have a mountain to climb so the [lower bound for rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1) is 1.

Comment: Interestingly the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq#reputation) doesn't seem to cover this, but yes - No matter how much of a git someone is (even to the point of a moderator suspending them) an account will never have reputation less than 1.

Comment: Considering that it takes five downvotes to counter the reputation effect of a single answer upvote, I'd figure that anyone at risk of negative rep most likely deserves it.

Comment: People with poor start can't even ask questions anymore and don't know enough to answer anything.

Comment: @SharenEayrs: Everyone who is working as a professional sysadmin should have some skills which would allow them to answer some questions and get themselves out of a question ban.